# NodeJS express rest API APP into angular 5 project

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express, angular5

I am new in programmation and i follow a tutorial in udemy to create my restful API with express JS.

I have almost finished my API and i want to integrate it in a new angular 5/6 project.

I have tried a lot of tutorials but i cannot launch my express project in an angular project to make a request with postman.

could you show me please ?

[Here is my express project](https://github.com/soosoo34/ParisSportifAPI)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described. Please include any error messages or stacktraces that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to "integrate" your NodeJs app with an Angular application.
You make a NodeJS REST API as you would with any other technology and run it separately on a certain port (Default is 3000 for NodeJS)
Run it with the command node app.js.

Then you make an Angular application, that connects to your API as if it would to any other page. A HTTP call inside a service to your specified link.

```
public contactAPI(){
        var uri = 'localhost:3000'; //Or whatever the link is for your node server
        return this.http.get(uri);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but how its work in production, can i host my express and angular project on the same server ?

What type of hosting I need to get my API and Angular routing on the same URL ?

for exemple :
my api to  "www.myhost.com/api/" 
and my angular to "www.myhost.com/index"/

Comment: Yes, you can host your express and angular project on the same server, it's both Javascript so it isn't really complex. You usually have to build Angular code and then deploy it together with NodeJs server.
This is an example of such application (MEAN stack):  [Github repo](https://github.com/mLenic/AteljePsihoterapije):

server - NodeJS files and src - Angular files.

Heroku has a great guide on [how to deploy a MEAN stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api#prerequisites). For testing purposes i suggest running both servers separately.